# Why do the results of the find command differ when the path is . and when it is ./*?

Tags: command-line, find

When I type `find . -name "so*"` I get all these results:

```
./sort
./.cache/evolution/sources
./.config/evolution/sources
./.local/share/sounds
```

But when I type `find ./* -name "so*"` I only get `./sort`.

From what I know when I use `.` in the command I am asking to find files that begin with "so" in my current directory, but when I use `./*` it displays only the `./sort` file and doesn't display the hidden files, so I am wondering what adding `/*` actually does and how it changes my query/instruction.

Comment: Both `.` and `./` refer to the current directory - I think maybe your confusion is because `find` by default returns all files (including hidden ones) whereas the shell glob `*` expands only to *non*-hidden files by default (in bash, you can modify that behaviour using the `dotglob` shell option). Also `find` descends recursively of course.

Answer (score 1):

`find .` means search from the current directory.

`find ./*` means search from all files and directories in the current directory that are matched by a `*`.

However, the `*` is expanded by the shell, so that `find` thinks you really typed a command like:

```
find ./sort ./another-dir ./another-file ./etc -name "so*"
```

Your observation is correct. By default, a leading `*` excludes files or directories beginning with a `.`, so they are never even seen by `find`.  This is not just hidden files, but also the current and parent directories, so `.*` usually isn't a good idea!

Comment: Why does the OP get *fewer* results with `./*`?